# Unable to display specific view for 404 errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code inside my app/start/global.php file:

```
App::missing(function($exception){
    return Response::view('missing', array('url' => Request::url()), 404);
});
```

And I have a file called missing.blade.php at app/view. However, the above code gives me a FatalErrorException, telling me "Call to a member function getPath() on a non-object". The formatting of the otherwise pretty error page that I got the above information from is also messed up.

But everything works fine when I change my code in global.php to the following:

```
App::missing(function($exception){
    return Response::make("Page not found", 404);
});
```

I don't get what's going on. How can I display a specific view when a route is not found?

**EDIT:**
Here is my missing.blade.php file:

```
@extends('master')

@section('header')
    <h2>404 Error</h2>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>
        Unable to locate page.
    </p>
@stop
```

**EDIT 2:**
Also inside my app/views folder, I have a master.blade.php file with the following structure:

```
...
@yield('header')
...
@yield('content')
...
```

Comment: Can we please see your missing.blade.php

Comment: I have added the contents of missing.blade.php in my edit above. I use the exact same layout in another file without problems (i.e. the @extends and @section's).

Comment: master.blade.php please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you and gives you more control on other errors as well:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    switch ($code)
    {
        case 403:
            return 'Your 403 message';//or load any custom view
             break;
        case 404:
             return Redirect::to('/');//or load any custom view
              break;
        case 500:
             return 'Your 500 Error Message';//or load any custom view
              break;
        default:
            return Redirect::to('/');//or load any custom view
    }
});
```

Comment: I replaced my "App::missing..." code with yours, and swapped the line "return Redirect::('/');" for case 404 to "return Response::view('missing');". Now when I try to go to a page that is not defined, it goes to that page and partially loads my template... weird.

Comment: that means that the redirect works fine, possibly an error in your view file? try simplifying your view file's content to the just 'hello world' and seeing if it works...

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, it works when I put something like "Hello world!" inside missing.blade.php. But then why does it not work with my templating markup?

Comment: @cornflakes24 Something in your view file is causing it to not work correctly, try debugging it with var_dump until you find the breakpoint. However, I believe that is a completely different issue. Consider closing this question and posting a new one, if this answer helped with the original problem feel free to mark it.